# Read regex value and use find()

Tags: java, regex

I want to read comments from .sql file and get the values:

```
<!--
    @author: batman
    @description: 100000
-->
```

Code:

```
String text = String.join("", Files.readAllLines(file.toPath()));

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("@(?<key>([\\w]+)?): (?<value>(.+)?)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);

while (matcher.find())
{
    if (matcher.group("key").equals("author")) {
        author = matcher.group("value");
    }

    if (matcher.group("key").equals("description")) {
        description = matcher.group("value");
    }    
}
```

When I use `matcher.find()` I get several iterations if `matcher` because I have several comments into XML file.

The idea is to get only the comment with the proper match and to skip the rest of the comments. Do you know why the code is not working fine?

I tried also with "@(?[\w]+): (?.*)" but again I get the same issue.

Edit: tested example:

```
public void printContent() throws Exception
        {
            String folder = "/opt/APP-INF/classes";
            List<File> list = listf(folder);

            out.println("<table>");
            out.println("<thead>");
            out.println("<tr>");
            out.println("<td>Type</td>"); // .class.sql/.xml
            out.println("<td>Author</td>");
            .......
            out.println("</tr>");
            out.println("</thead>");
            out.println("<tbody>");

            for(File file : list)
            {
                String fullPackagePath = file.getPath();

                if(file.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".xml"))
                {
                    XMLStreamReader xr = XMLInputFactory.newInstance().createXMLStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));

                    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*@(?<key>(author|description|fix|ticket|release)): (?<value>.*?)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);

                    while (xr.hasNext())
                    {
                        if (xr.next() == XMLStreamConstants.COMMENT) {

                            String comment = xr.getText();
                            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(comment);

                            if(!matcher.find()){
                                continue;
                            }

                            out.println("<tr>");
                            out.println("<td> .xml </td>");

                            String author = "N/A";
                            .....    
                            while (matcher.find())
                            {
                                if (matcher.group("key").equals("author")) {
                                    author = matcher.group("value");
                                }

                                ........
                            }

                            out.println("<td>" + author + "</td>");
                            ......    
                            try (                               
                            out.println("</tr>");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            out.println("</tbody>");
            out.println("</table>");
        }

        private List<File> listf(String directoryName) {
            File directory = new File(directoryName);

            List<File> resultList = new ArrayList<File>();

            // get all the files from a directory
            File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
            resultList.addAll(Arrays.asList(fList));
            for (File file : fList) {
                if (file.isFile()) {
                } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
                    resultList.addAll(listf(file.getAbsolutePath()));
                }
            }

            return resultList;
        }
```

Comment: Use: `String.join("\n", Files.readAllLines(file.toPath()))`

Comment: It's a bit unclear, but probably matching the two values within one regex will work for you, see https://ideone.com/ge6Cm0

Comment: Can you show me how to get the param using names not numbers, please?

Comment: You are already doing it in your code. Just edit the code to make them named groups. @PeterPenzov

Comment: I'm not getting what things you want to extract from comments ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I got what you mean, that's what you want to do:

This is the text file sample:

```
<!--
    @author: batman
    @description: 100000
-->
<!--
    @author: batman
    @description: 200000
-->
<!--
    @author: batman
    @description: 300000
-->
<!--
    @author: batman
    @description: 400000
-->
<!--
    @author: batman
    @description: 500000
-->
<!--
    @author: batman
    @description: 600000
-->
<!--
    @author: batman
    @description: 700000
-->
<!--
   esse não
-->
<!--
    @author: batman
    @description: 800000
-->

<!--
   esse não
-->
<!--
    @author: batman
    @description: 800000
    @anothertagtoconsider: value_Tag
-->
```

And that's the code to search for the occurences:

```
public class RegexProblem {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String content = String.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"), Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(RegexProblem.class.getResource("/regex.txt").toURI())));
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*@(?<key>(author|description)): (?<value>.*?)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);

        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(content);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            String key = matcher.group("key");
            String value = matcher.group("value");
            System.out.printf("%s -> %s%n", key, value);
        }
    }
}
```

And that's the output:

```
author -> batman
description -> 100000
author -> batman
description -> 200000
author -> batman
description -> 300000
author -> batman
description -> 400000
author -> batman
description -> 500000
author -> batman
description -> 600000
author -> batman
description -> 700000
author -> batman
description -> 800000
```

Comment: this pattern looks interesting but can you expand the example a little more please with one more type of key and value?

Comment: Now I've got it, the annotation name @ should be the key, and what comes after the colon should be the value, isn't it? But you'd like to match only author and description, not all of the tags? I've edited with one more type of key and value to check this...

Comment: Yes. This is the general idea because we have several keys

Comment: I have one question: When I added `if(!matcher.find()){
                                continue;
                            }` in order to skip comments which don't have the searched patterns I get exception. Can you try the code please?

Comment: After testing if the matcher can actually find, you should call pattern.matcher(text) again to grab the occurrences, it's not a good idea to reuse the matcher, however, I couldn't see why you're getting Exception, btw, what exception is being thrown in your code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214168/discussion-between-s-bighead-and-peter-penzov).

Comment: See you into the chat